# Vector cross product

Tags: vector-spaces

I have this question on my take home assignment and it is giving me a headache.

Find the volume of the parallelepiped with three edges formed by $ \langle 2,1,0 \rangle,\ \langle -1,2,0 \rangle  \ \text{and} \  \langle 1,1,2 \rangle $ using the cross product.

Comment: Since they said i should use cross product,i found it first but i didn't know what to do with it. I found the product between a and b and its this third component that is making it harder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you'll need the scalar triple product, which is a dot product of a vector with a cross product of the other two vectors. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product